# Rewriting IConfiguration appsettings.json with Command Line Arguments in C# 10 .NET 6

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I'm making console application in `C# 10 .NET 6` using the `Dependency Injection`.
I have an appsettings.json file that i load by `IConfiguration` but i have also added a custom `IConfigurationSource` that loads data in a specific way by the `Command Line Arguments`.
It works because if i write a CLA that overrides an `appsettings.json` property then it does.
What I want to do is that if i override a particular `appsettings.json` property via `CLA` I want it to update the property inside the `appsettings.json` file so I don't have to start the application with the same `CLA` again and again. How do I accomplish that?

```
private IConfiguration SetUpConfiguration()
{
    IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddAppSettingsFile()
    .AddCommandLineArgumentBuilder(_args)
    .Build();
    return configuration;
}
```

I Wrote it in a simplified version to make you see the "structure" of what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to derive from [JsonConfigurationProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.json.jsonconfigurationprovider) and override the [Set-Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationprovider.set) so it actually writes values back to the file.

Comment: I tried to create new classes for JsonConfigurationProvider and JsonConfigurationSource to override the Set method but it is not being called when an another IConfigurationSource overrides the Data